# What are the possible Batch Operations in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, csom, pnp-powershell, batch

I have a requirement to move just attachments from list A to list B. It's a large list with multiple attachments in each item. I know REST batching is one option, but I was wondering if CSOM, PowerShell had batching options as well. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the following article:

Copy Attachments from One List to Another using PowerShell

https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/02/sharepoint-online-copy-attachments-from-one-list-to-another-using-powershell.html

In addition, you can also use flow to complete such a requirement:

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Flow-Discussion/Copy-attachments-from-one-SharePoint-list-to-another-list/td-p/90247